# Write a normal DVD from a rip

Tags: dvd, media

How could I go about the 'opposite' of ripping a DVD, i.e. given an .avi file, create a DVD that will play in older DVD players, those that don't offer 'naked' file support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/) will encode media files (and burn them) as a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Use a program such as DeVeDe to turn it back into a VIDEO_TS structure or an appropriate ISO.